# add hyperlink to customized username area in aspx webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx web page there is one area to display username like `Hi, Sruthy`. It is customized to each user. So now I want to add hyperlink to this area how can I do it?

**So my code is:**

```
<div id="Displayname" class="displayName" runat="server">
    <a href="Personalinfo.aspx" target=_blank></a>
</div>
```

Comment: please check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `<asp:Hyperlink>`

**HTML**

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hl1" 
                  NavigateUrl="#"
                  Text=""
                  runat="server"/>
```

**C#**

you can alter the href or Text  in C# using

```
 hl1.NavigateUrl = "#"; 
  hl1.Text = "Hi,Sruthy";
```